# Laravel 5: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 - Many to Many

Tags: php, laravel

I need some advice on the following.

I have 2 migrations, like so.

```
        Schema::create('plates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('serial_number');
        $table->string('crc-code', 50);
        $table->string('reason', 50)->nullable();

        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And another one

```
  Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 25)->unique();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->longText('relative_path');
```

A pivot table for many to many relations I have setup just like this

```
        Schema::create('document_plate', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->integer('plate_id')->unsigned()->index();
      $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned()->index();

      $table->primary(['plate_id', 'document_id']);

      $table->timestamps();
    });
```

When taking a certain action I use the code below to attach a `plate` to a `document`

```
       $plate  =   Plate::find(1);
       $doc    =   Document::find(1);
       if($plate && $doc) {
          $plate->documents()->attach($doc->id);
       }
```

The first time, everything works just fine! the `document_plate` gets updated. The error occurs when having the same `ids` doing it again.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `document_plate` (`created_at`, `document_id`, `plate_id`, `updated_at`)

Now the **question**

Is there a way to avoid getting errors and just update the table with the same `ids`??

Or.. I need to setup a some sort of validation on the front-end which tells the user (before submitting) that he/she choose the same `id's` which are already in the table.

Note: I am using AngularJS for front-end operations.

Comment: Looks like Laravel does not just handle this automatically, except in the case of using `->sync([ids])`. However, it's not hard to get around (just a shame) - just query for the existence first. But my best advice is to see if you can change your code to use `->sync()` rather than `->attach()`. It handles additions, updates and deletions from the pivot table all in one place. You just need to have the full list of IDs you need at the end of the process (so it's not ideal if you just want to add-if-not-exists).

Comment: @alexrussell Just a follow up. How would you do it if you had my code above?  `$plate->documents()->sync();` won't work of course.

Comment: sync() requires all the id's that should be attached passed in an array. Any id's not included in that array will be removed.

Comment: also I am pretty sure eloquent dosent support composite primary key https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355 so you need to give primary id to the document_plate table

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laravel makes this very simple to achieve by using the `sync` method. The `sync` method by default will detach any ids that you don't pass to it, but it accepts a second argument that can disable the detaching.

```
$plate->documents()->sync([$doc->id], false);
```

This will only add the entry if it does not already exist in the table.

Link to the API: http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_sync

Comment: Ahh I didn't know about this and I was even looking at the code when writing my comment above. Derp. Good spot.

Comment: The link to those docs is old and broken, but I did solve my issue by reading the latest docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations. For the example above the equivalent would be `$user->roles()->syncWithoutDetaching([1, 2, 3]);`, however the bit that solved my integrity problem was separating the relation ID from the extra pivot data -  `$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);`