# Creating Follower & Following relationships in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to create a function in laravel that will return all the user's followers through Laravel's dynamic property. It should look something like this:`$user->followers`.

I also have the following table structures:

```
--users--
id pk

--follows--
follower pk,fk
following pk,fk
```

I was trying to use the hasManyThrough function in the model but I haven seen  an example in the documentation that lets me specify a custom primary key aside from an incremental id.

Comment: I am not sure why you would have two separate tables for followers/following. Wouldn't a single table to keep record of whose following who be enough?

Comment: No I have one table called follows that sees whos following whom. The above table is the user table. both the followers and following fields are foreign keys to the user table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Citing from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> If you would like to customize the keys of the relationship, you may pass them as the third and fourth arguments to thehasManyThrough method. The third argument is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model, while the fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final model.

You should be able to pass your custom foreign key column names as described there.

--EDIT:
After some reflection, I think `hasManyThrough` is not adequate for what you want to achieve (at least with the little information provided in the question). Instead `belongsToMany` should do:

In a fresh Laravel 5.2 installation, I created a **migration** for such pivot table (inspired by another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673724/error-with-migrate-refresh/35675089#35675089)):

```
 public function up()
 {
     Schema::create('follows', function (Blueprint $table) {
         // Edit 2 without an incremental id
         // $table->increments('id');
         $table->integer('follower_id')->unsigned();
         $table->integer('followee_id')->unsigned();
         $table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')
               ->on('users')
               ->onDelete('cascade');
         $table->foreign('followee_id')->references('id')
               ->on('users')
               ->onDelete('cascade');

         // Edit 2: with primary and unique constraint
         $table->primary(['follower_id', 'followee_id']);
         $table->unique(['follower_id', 'followee_id']);
     });
 }
```

And in **App\User** Model

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        self::class, 
        'follows',
        'followee_id',
        'follower_id'
    );
}
public function followees()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        self::class,
        'follows',
        'follower_id',
        'followee_id'
    );
}
```

Then, after seeding some users and pivot relations, this works for me:

```
$user = User::first();
// user is followed by
echo json_encode($user->followers()->get());
// user is following
echo json_encode($user->followees()->get());
```

In a first version of this (trivial) example there were two primary keys: 'id' on 'users' and 'id' on 'follows', i.e. the defaults by convention. You can override your pk in your model like so `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';`. There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030716/change-default-primary-key-in-eloquent) on SO on this.
Now the pivot table has a composite key which must be unique, which was the OPs intention I guess.

-- Edit 2:
With the constraints in place you should add followers like so:

```
$user->followers()->sync([$anotherUser->id],false);
```

in order to avoid integrity constraint violation if the composite key should exist already. The sync method is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022415/laravel-5-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-many-to-many).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I need to specify the primary as my question states.

Comment: Now I am confused, sorry. You have a pivot table 'follows', right? Which column shall be primary, incremental on it? Do you have any migration code you could share?

Comment: the primary key is the combination of follower and followee. Do you think this i bad practice and just put a unique constraint on the combination? Do you think I should make it an increment? I'll look into your answer. thanks for giving me some code to expand on btw. I really appreciate it

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I see, you may use composite keys as well of course. Though I cannot judge which would be the better practice. Maybe someone else? Anyway, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. belongsToMany is what I am looking for :D. I especially did benefit from your self::class command.

Comment: Thanks ! It works just fine :) I wrote a small gist for usage with jenssegers/laravel-mongodb database driver https://gist.github.com/AndreiTelteu/ec8c8d077a8b77936ad53a7e66e6e51a